# Only view MathJax in preview on button press

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, markdown-preview

Could there be a selection box / button just below the editing box, and before the Markdown Preview to enable / disable the MathJax.

When I was editing a question, I was finding it quite distracting that ever time I typed something, the box jumped about because of the height of the MathJax. It had o refresh every time, and this was quite irritating.

I would like to be able to enable / disable the MathJax sections before I have finished editing - perhaps with a toggling button or a check box.

Comment: I suppose you are aware of [robjohn's bookmarklets](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/mathjax-makes-preview-flicker/9737#9737).

Comment: What's a bookmarklet?

Comment: You can find out on Wikipedia what [bookmaklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) is. But for this particular bookmarklet, if you follow the links you will find detailed description and installation instuctions written by robjohn.

Comment: BTW the linked question [MathJax makes preview flicker](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/mathjax-makes-preview-flicker) could be almost considered a duplicate. The only difference is that in the other feature request, this is only one of the two proposed solutions for this problem.

Comment: If you want to flag as dupe, please do. However, this question does fulfil the comment asking for a proper solution.